# cx_oracle Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle

Tags: django, oracle, python-2.7, database-connection, cx-oracle

When trying to get a connection to an Oracle Database I´m getting the following error:

```
File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    conn = cx_Oracle.Connection('dbuser/dbpass@fqdn')
cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle
```

The Test code:

```
import os
#os.environ['ORACLE_HOME']='/oracle/client/112_64/'
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.Connection('dbuser/dbpass@fqdn')
```

My Paths are set like this:

```
ORACLE_BASE=/oracle/oracle-client
ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/oracle-client/112_64
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/oracle/client/112_64/:/oracle/oracle-client/112_64/lib/
PATH=/oracle/oracle-client/112_64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/my_user/bin
```

The installed Oracle Version is 11g according to `libocci.so.11.1` and the cx_Oracle Version is 5.2.1

I dont´t know what the problem could be. Can some give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error (Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle) is Oracle's way of telling you that there is something wrong with your configuration. In your case you have differing paths which may be the source of the problem. One says "/oracle/oracle-client" and the other says "/oracle/client". You should find out which one is correct and adjust things accordingly.

You can use SQL*Plus to connect to the database. If that works then cx_Oracle should also work.

You can also use the ldd command to find out if the system is finding the correct library. Like this:

```
ldd /path/to/cx_Oracle.so
```

This error can also appear if you have a version of cx_Oracle compiled against 12c but are using an 11g client (for example). Or you have bits and pieces of two different clients being loaded at the same time. But in your case I strongly suspect the conflicting paths!

If you are on a Linux distribution that is RPM based (Oracle Linux, Red Hat Linux, Fedora, etc.) I would strongly recommend using the instant client RPMs that are provided. They make configuration extremely simple and no environment variables are required to build and install cx_Oracle (as of 5.2). You can find them here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

Comment: Thank you for your hint. There where two things. The path was not set globally and second the access rights where not set correctly for the network folder.